# Using Greasemonkey to change a <script> on the current HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

I am wondering if this could be possible. For example I go to an web page, its source code like:

```
<html>
    <script scr="path/file.js"></script>
</html>
```

Then I write a Grease monkey script to this html page, and it will replace the

```
<script scr="/path/file.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script scr="/path/anotherfile.js"></script>
```

assume 'anotherfile.js' does exist in the server side. And the current html page will change accordingly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Alright, so you want to replace a script file using the Greasemonkey addon, correct?  Assuming so, then yes, it is possible.  The Greasemonkey addon operations permit its scripts to run on a web pages HTML before or after the page is rendered in your browser.  For this case, you would want it to render before it is rendered.  If you implement that script after rendering, you'd have to negate everything the original script file did before the new one can run without interference.

Comment: I am still confused: the 'anotherfile.js' is not in the browser unless you make another request to the server, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use GreaseMonkey myself.  For something like this, I'd use server-side scripting to re-rendering the page as I wanted it.  My understanding of GreaseMonkey is that if you tell it to swap code before rendering it in the browser, then the new code would be rendered instead of the original.

Comment: Let me ask in this way: will the page you using grease monkey script changes immediately after it replace the 'file.js' with 'anotherfile.js' in the html? I mean the 'anotherfile.js' is not in the browser at all, right? Do you mean that the grease monkey script changes the html content and grab that 'anotherfile.js' from the server and shows another html page related to 'anotherfile.js'?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking.  Basically, the way browser operate is that contact the web server and download the HTML code for the target web page.  Once that HTML code is on your computer, it then renders the page, pulling external files linked in the code (JS and CSS files) as it loads.  What you can do with GreaseMonkey is to modify the HTML code before it starts to render the page, allowing you to attach an alternate JS file.  Will this change the content/appearance of the page?  That depends on what you have programmed into the new JS file.  Also, this isn't permanent.

Comment: I think I got the point, thanks for the explanation!